# Has reached its natural boundary (meaning)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is I think a bit idiomatic:

> "Of the 26 species that are known to have become successfully integrated into the local environment, only one, an African species released in northern Australia, **has reached its natural boundary.**

What does this phrase mean exactly? This is vague...

Comment: The introduced species has reached a point where local environmental conditions make it unable to spread any further.

Comment: So they died or just been limited?

Comment: Suppose one of the geographical boundaries is a river. Perhaps any animals that cross the river immediately get eaten by some particularly successful predator when they reach the other side, so ***they die***. Or perhaps this species doesn't like water, or can't swim, so ***they're limited*** (by that water boundary). The net effect is the same, and in your cited example it's irrelevant exactly ***how*** the geographical spread of the species has been constrained (all we know for sure is it's not a matter of human intervention, such as myxomatosis supposedly limiting the spread of rabbits).

Comment: I think some context clues are needed, besides the language itself to understand this.   Based on some of my understanding of biology, and inferring some things this article might actually be about - I think Kate's comment is probably the correct sense.  But you have to think about what the article is trying to say.